# Read the client clipboard with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, clipboard

Is it possible to get/read the clipboard of a client with jQuery?

(I need get the information of a spread sheet and paste this information in a jqGrid web grid...)

Comment: Good question with no good answer?...

Comment: Should be possible using flash the same as copy to clipboard, but I can't find existing code that do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround to accomplish the request. Basically I included a TextBox object into my Web Form with the legend "Paste your information [Here]. Using CTRL + V". 
Then, I read the event pressKey with jQuery (reading CTRL + V combination), then I can read the clipboard data in the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Well according [to this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript) it cannot be done with just JavaScript. Which is good, because it would be a major security risk. You need a small flash object to get the functionality you want.

In any way, this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Its also a question that can be solved with a simple Google query.

Comment: Yeah it isn't a javascript thing. Except in IE. Funny this is the only cool part of IE (IE6 does it without question, IE7 alert the user about it).

Comment: thanks to answer!

But I been reading in ZeroClipboard web page, and I found that with this object not is possible to read the clipboard...

Anybody have any other idea?

Comment: @BernardMarx- This isn't a duplicate - the answer you point to is about writing to clipboard, and MiBol's asking about reading from clipboard.

Comment: This is a really, really old question.  look at this:  http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/Gfw3D/

Answer (score 0):

Does [DataDrop – Drag Grid Data in From a Spreadsheet](http://www.vinylfox.com/datadrop-drag-grid-data-from-spreadsheet/) help? It would be drag & drop instead of reading the clipboard, but reading the clipboard is difficult to impossible.