# How do you recognize if someone has something on their clipboard?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a Image Host Service, now people can copy images in their clipboard and press control + V to paste them and upload.

Now i want to detect if they have images in their clipboard like:
"You have 7 images in your clipboard. Press control + v to upload them"
I am using PHP and jQuery for the clipboard paste.

Is this possible?

Kind Regards

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Nobody will ever have seven images in their clipboard.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content

Comment: Why not @LightnessRacesinOrbit , you can copy 7 images in your image folder :)?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744621/read-the-client-clipboard-with-jquery

Comment: @MODEV: No you can't. You can copy seven paths. The Windows clipboard contains only one slot for binary data.

Comment: PHP won't do it anyway since it's executed server-side and clipboards are client-side.

Comment: Well, ill put my site online: Scrshot.com , select 7 images from a image path, and press control + v (control paste) now 7 images are uploading.

Comment: @MODEV: That does not mean that there are seven images in the clipboard.

Comment: But if you uploaded 7 images it means you had 7 images in your clipboard?

Comment: @MODEV: No, it does not. Read some more about how the clipboard works. It only contained the paths of those files. You _can_ store actual image data in the clipboard, but only one at a time, and not from the Windows shell. ("Copy Image" from your browser is an example of this.)

Comment: @StevenLiao , i already have that .. This is a other question. Thanks for helping anyways.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , thanks for this explain, i didnt know this. Sorry! :)

Comment: Hope you find your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Not with the technologies you have listed, and I doubt many others. (this is not a comment, this is the answer)

Comment: Thanks Daryl, if it was possible it would be nice.